# Resolving the method of a ABAP dynamic call: order of types considered

Tags: abap

I try to provoke a behaviour described in the [ABAP Keyword Documentation 7.50](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/index.htm?file=abapcall_method_meth_ident_dyna.htm) but fail.  It's given with Alternative 2 of `CALL METHOD - dynamic_meth`:

> CALL METHOD oref->(meth_name) ...
>
> Effect
>
> ... oref can be any class reference variable ... that points to an object that contains the method  ... specified in meth_name. This method is searched for first in the static type, then in the dynamic type of oref

I use the test code as given below. The static type of `oref` is `CL1`, the dynamic type `CL2`. Shouldn't then the dynamic `CALL METHOD` statement call the method `M` in `CL1`?

```
REPORT ZU_DEV_2658_DYNAMIC.

CLASS CL1 DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS M.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS CL1 IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD M.
    write / 'original'.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS CL2 DEFINITION INHERITING FROM CL1.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS M REDEFINITION.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS CL2 IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD M.
    write / 'redefinition'.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.

DATA oref TYPE REF TO cl1.    " static type is CL1
CREATE OBJECT oref TYPE cl2.  " dynamic type is CL2

oref->m( ).                   " writes 'redefinition' - that's ok
CALL METHOD oref->('M').      " writes 'redefinition' - shouldn't that be 'original'?
```

Update:

I'd like to answer to the (first four) comments to my original question. Because of the lengthy code snippet, I answer by augmenting my post, not by comment.

It is true that the behaviour of the code snippet of the original question is standard OO behaviour. It's also true that for calls with static method name and class, types are resolved as given by the link. But then:

1. Why does the ABAP Keyword Documentation make the statement I've linked?
2. Calls with dynamic method names *do* search for the method name in the dynamic type, as demonstrated by the following code piece. That's certainly not standard OO behaviour.

My question was: Apparently, the search mechanism differs from the one described. Is the description wrong or else do I miss something?

```
REPORT ZU_DEV_2658_DYNAMIC4.

CLASS CL_A DEFINITION.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS CL_B DEFINITION INHERITING FROM CL_A.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS M2 IMPORTING VALUE(caller) TYPE c OPTIONAL PREFERRED PARAMETER caller.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS CL_B IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD M2.
    write / caller && ' calls b m2'.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.

DATA orefaa TYPE REF TO cl_a.   
CREATE OBJECT orefaa TYPE cl_a.   " static and dynamic type is CL_A

*orefaa->m2( 'orefa->m2( )' ). syntax error: method m2 is unknown'.
*CALL METHOD orefaa->('M2') EXPORTING caller = 'CALL METHOD orefa->("M2")'. results in exception: method m2 is unknown'.

DATA orefab TYPE REF TO cl_a.     " static type is CL_A
CREATE OBJECT orefab TYPE cl_b.   " dynamic type is CL_B

*orefab->m2( 'orefab->m2( )' ). results in syntax error: method m2 is unknown'.
CALL METHOD orefab->('M2') EXPORTING caller = 'CALL METHOD orefab->("M2")'. " succeeds
```

Comment: No, it shouldn't. The polymorphism still applies here regardless whether you use static or dynamic method call.

Comment: The static and dynamic applies here rather to static (class) methods and dynamic (reference) methods.

Comment: This is standard OO behaviour. At least it would be very strange, in case of a dynamic methid call, the call would happen on a higher level in the class hierarchy.

Comment: It is aligned with other languages and is described in [help](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abeninheritance_redefinition.htm): *Each reference that points to a subclass object uses the redefined method, even if it was typed with reference to a superclass. In particular, this also applies to the self reference me. ... Within a redefined method, super->meth can be used to access the obscured method, for example to apply and supplement its functions.*

Comment: No idea what this text in the ABAP documentation means. Internal technical stuff maybe, concerning lookup performance? (i.e. if you have an additional method `N` in `CL2`, and you do `CALL METHOD oref->('N')` it would search first `N` in `CL1` and as it doesn't exist it would then search `N` in `CL2`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually answering your own question there, aren't you?

In your first example, you perform a `call method` to the method `m` on a variable that's typed as `cl1`. The runtime looks up the class `cl1`, and finds the requested method `m` there. It then calls that method. However, your variable actually has the type `cl2`, a sub-class of `cl1`, that overrides that method `m`. So the call effectively reaches that redefinition of the method, not the super-class's original implementation. As you and the commenters sum it up: this is standard object-oriented behavior.

Note how in essence this has nothing to do at all with the static-vs-dynamic statement you quote from the documentation. The method `m` is *statically* present in `cl1`, so there is no dynamic lookup involved whatsoever. I assume you were looking for a way to probe the meaning of this statement, but this example doesn't address it.

However, your second example then precisely hits the nail on the head. Let me rewrite it again with different names to talk it through. Given an empty super class `super_class`:

```
CLASS super_class DEFINITION.
ENDCLASS.
```

and a sub-class `sub_class` that inherits it:

```
CLASS sub_class DEFINITION
  INHERITING FROM super_class.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS own_method.
ENDCLASS.
```

Now, as `super_class` is empty, `sub_class` does not take over any methods there. In contrast, we add a method `own_method` specifically to this class.

The following statement sequence then demonstrates exactly what's special with the dynamic calling:

```
DATA cut TYPE REF TO super_class.
cut = NEW sub_class( ).
CALL METHOD cut->('OWN_METHOD').
" runs sub_class->own_method
```

The runtime encounters the `call method` statement. It first inspects the static type of the variable `cut`, which is `super_class`. The requested method `own_method` is not present there. If this was all that happened, the call would now fail with a method-not-found exception. If we wrote a hard-coded `cut->own_method( )`, we wouldn't even get this far - the compiler would already reject this.

However, with `call method` the runtime continues. It determines the dynamic type of `cut` as being `sub_class`. Then it looks whether it finds an `own_method` *there*. And indeed, it does. The statement is accepted and the call is directed to `own_method`. This additional effort that's happening here is exactly what's described in the documentation as "This method is searched for first in the static type, *then in the dynamic type of oref*".

What we're seeing here is different from hard-coded method calls, but it is also not "illegal". In essence, the runtime here first `cast`s the variable `cut` to its dynamic type `sub_class`, then looks up the available methods again. As if we were writing `DATA(casted) = CAST super_class( cut ). casted->own_method( )`. I cannot say why the runtime acts this way. It feels like the kind of relaxed behavior we usually find in ABAP when statements evolve throughout their lifetime and need to remain backwards-compatible.

There is one detail that needs additional addressing: the tiny word "then" in the documentation. Why is it important to say that it *first* looks in the static type, *then* in the dynamic type? In the example above, it could simply say "and/or" instead.

Why this detail may be important is described in my second answer to your question, which I posted some days ago. Let me wrap it up shortly again here, so this answer here is complete. Given an interface with a method `some_method`:

```
INTERFACE some_interface PUBLIC.
  METHODS some_method RETURNING VALUE(result) TYPE string.
ENDINTERFACE.
```

and a class that implements it, but also adds another method of its own, with the exact same name `some_method`:

```
CLASS some_class DEFINITION PUBLIC.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    INTERFACES some_interface.
    METHODS some_method RETURNING VALUE(result) TYPE string.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS some_class IMPLEMENTATION.

  METHOD some_interface~some_method.
    result = `Executed the interface's method`.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD some_method.
    result = `Executed the class's method`.
  ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.
```

Which one of the two methods is now called by `CALL METHOD cut->('some_method')`? The order in the documentation describes it:

```
DATA cut TYPE REF TO some_interface.
cut = NEW some_class( ).
DATA result TYPE string.

CALL METHOD cut->('SOME_METHOD')
  RECEIVING
    result = result.

cl_abap_unit_assert=>assert_equals(
    act = result
    exp = `Executed the interface's method` ).
```

Upon encountering the `call method` statement, the runtime checks the static type of the variable `cut` first, which is `some_interface`. This type has a method `some_method`. The runtime thus will continue to call this method. This, again is standard object orientation. Especially note how this example calls the method `some_method` by giving the string `some_method` alone, although its fully qualified name is actually `some_interface~some_method`. This is consistent with the hard-coded variant `cut->some_method( )`.

If the runtime acted the other way around, inspecting the dynamic type first, and the static type afterwards, it would act differently and call the class's own method `some_method` instead.

There is no way to call the class's own `some_method`, by the way. Although the documentation suggests that the runtime would consider `cut`'s dynamic type `some_class` in a second step, it also adds that "In the dynamic case too, only interface components can be accessed and it is not possible to use interface reference variable to access any type of component."

The only way to call the class's own method `some_method`, is by changing `cut`'s type:

```
DATA cut TYPE REF TO some_class.
cut = NEW some_class( ).
DATA result TYPE string.

CALL METHOD cut->('SOME_METHOD')
  RECEIVING
    result = result.

cl_abap_unit_assert=>assert_equals(
    act = result
    exp = `Executed the class's method` ).
```

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer. Just for some background: I'm basically re-implementing the ABAP resolution mechanism in Java. It is applied at compile time and for a call should yield all call targets that could possibly selected at runtime - and only those, of course. Your answer does very much help.

Comment: Ah, that explains the extensive level of detail you require here. 

Answer (score 0):

This is rather about interface implementations than class inheritance. What the ABAP language help means is this:

Suppose you have an interface that declares a method

```
INTERFACE some_interface PUBLIC.
  METHODS some_method RETURNING VALUE(result) TYPE string.
ENDINTERFACE.
```

and a class that implements it, but alongside also declares a method with the same name, of its own

```
CLASS some_class DEFINITION PUBLIC.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    INTERFACES some_interface.
    METHODS some_method RETURNING VALUE(result) TYPE string.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS some_class IMPLEMENTATION.

  METHOD some_interface~some_method.
    result = `Executed the interface's method`.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD some_method.
    result = `Executed the class's method`.
  ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.
```

then a dynamic call on a reference variable typed with the interface will choose the interface method over the class's own method

```
METHOD prefers_interface_method.

  DATA cut TYPE REF TO zfh_some_interface.
  cut = NEW zfh_some_class( ).
  DATA result TYPE string.

  CALL METHOD cut->('SOME_METHOD')
    RECEIVING
      result = result.

  cl_abap_unit_assert=>assert_equals(
      act = result
      exp = `Executed the interface's method` ).

ENDMETHOD.
```

This is actually the exact same behavior we are observing with regular calls to methods, i.e. if we provide the method's name in the code, not in a variable.

Only if the runtime cannot find a method with the given name in the static type will it start looking for a method with that name in the dynamic type. This is different from regular method calls, where the compiler will reject the missing `some_interface~` and require us to add an `alias` for this to work.

By the way, as some people brought it up in the comments, the "static" here does not refer to `CLASS-METHODS`, as opposed to "instance" methods. "Static type" and "dynamic type" refer to different things, see [the section *Static Type and Dynmic Type* in the help article *Assignment Rules for Reference Variables*](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/index.htm?file=abapcall_method_meth_ident_dyna.htm).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the relation to interfaces. Two comments: 1) You say `Only if the runtime  cannot find a method with the given name in the static type will it start looking for a method with that name in the dynamic type. This is different from regular method calls ...` I tried to provoke that behaviour by commenting out the method declaration in `some_interface` and its implementation in `some_class` but the both calls fail, i.e., behave the same. Could you provide a working code example? 2) How do you explain the behaviour demonstrated by the second code piece in my original post?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot edit my comment anymore. With `provide a working code example`, I meant a code example that demonstrates your point, i.e., the difference in behaviour.